# How to pass a generic struct and get the list of its properties in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, struct

I have multiple struct in my project and I need the list of properties from the struct. So basically I need a utility function to which I should be able to pass the struct and that function should return the string array of the properties in the struct.

```
struct TestModel: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let secondsSinceEpoch: Int

    init(id: Int, secondsSinceEpoch: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.secondsSinceEpoch = secondsSinceEpoch
    }

    func propertyNames()  -> [String] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return mirror.children.compactMap{ $0.label }
    }
}
```

Here, I use the function `propertyNames()` to get the property names from `TestModel`.

```
let propertyList = TestModel(id: 1, secondsSinceEpoch: 2).propertyNames()
```

Similarly, I need a generic function something like this.

```
func propertyNames<T>(structure: T)  -> [String] {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: T.self)
    return mirror.children.compactMap{ $0.label }
}
```

And I should be able to pass any struct to get the list of properties.

```
let propertyList = propertyNames(structure: TestModel.self)
```

But this returns an empty array.

Comment: It needs to be `Mirror(reflecting: structure.self)` and you need to pass an object not a type to the function.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I need to make the function generic so that I can pass diff structures to that function.

Comment: This sounds like it may be an XY problem. But, as Joakim said, Mirror is only for use on instances. There is no capability in Swift to introspect types

Comment: The Swift runtime has the metadata for answering these kinds of reflection queries, but there's no API that exposes them. There are third party reflection libraries that tap into that data, but I can almost guarantee that what you're trying to do can be better addressed by Codable, Property Wrappers or Macros. So then then as other alluded, the next question is: what exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: This would definitely be the job of a macro. It should be relatively straightforward with that, though. (As everyone has noted, a function cannot do this.) For an introduction, see https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10166/  (If you run into a particular problem writing the macro, you can ask a question about that. We're all still learning how to write them.)

Comment: You need to pass an object and if you accept that then the function doesn’t need to be generic, you can use `Any` as the argument type.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a typo in your method. The correct version would be:

```
func propertyNames<T>(structure: T)  -> [String] {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: structure)
    return mirror.children.compactMap{ $0.label }
}
```

Before, it was mirroring the *type* instead of an instance of that type. It also matches the implementation that's inside `TestModel`.

Comment: Mirroring the *type* is what the OP wants to do, but this is not something you can do in Swift.  You can only use `Mirror` on *instances* as your answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but this could be the solution:

You can actually pass a class or struct, not just an object as such, to `Mirror`

```
        let smirror = Mirror(reflecting: SomeStruct.self)
        for (name, value) in smirror.children {
            print("\(name) .. \(value)")
        }
```

Could that be what you need?